# What is the VB.NET syntax for using List.FindAll() with a lambda?

Tags: c#, vb.net, predicate, generic-list, findall

In C# I have been performing a FindAll in a generic list as follows:

```
List<group.category> tlist = list.FindAll(p => p.parid == titem.catid);
```

Two questions, is this the appropriate way of performing such a thing and how do I convert this to VB.Net

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, yes this is the appropriate way to do this and secondly:

```
Dim tlist As List(Of group.category) _
    = list.FindAll(Function(p) p.parid = titem.catid)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. reverting back to VB from C# makes me feel stupid